# How to change style of element based on different data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a user's profile page, and depending on the user type I have `status` of variable that changes. There are the statuses

```
0 gues user
1 user registered but email not verified
2 user registered and verified
3 user blocked
```

I am trying to show an icon instead of the numbers, so I am doing it this way

...

```
<span v-if='user.status == 0' class='fa fa-close'> </span>
<span v-if='user.status == 1' class='fa fa-envelope'> </span>
<span v-if='user.status == 3' class='fa fa-check'> </span>
<span v-if='user.status == 4' class='fa fa-ban'> </span>
```

...

As you can see this code is very verbose and I am looking for something to avoid writing a code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Class Binding documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad)

In your example, you could bind the icon, based on the user's status. The template will look like :

```
<span :class=`fa fa-${getIconFromStatus(user.status)}`></span>
```

And in the component's script, you'll add this method :

```
getIconFromStatus(status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 0 : 
      return 'close';
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look at the docs. I have thought about this but it looks somewhat cumbersome also

Comment: You can always just bind the class to the method, and in this method return the classes but you will lighten the template only to make the switch more redundant.
Template : 
`<span :class="getIconFromStatus(user.status)"></span>` 
and the cases' returned values will be like :
`return 'fa fa-close'`